# Post to Fan Page Wall, status OK, but post doesn't show on Wall

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, symfony

I am trying to implement a functionality to publish post to Facebook Fan Page from Admin page (SonataAdminBundle) for Symfony 2 Framework. I've integrated Facebook PHP SDK and in Controller tried to use this:

```
        $facebook = new \Facebook(array(
            'appId'  => $myAppId,
            'secret' => $myAppSecret,
            'cookie' => false,
            ));


        //Get App Token
        $token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
        //Try to Publish on wall or catch the Facebook exception
        try {

          $args = array('access_token' => $token,
            'from' => $myAppId,
            'link' => 'http://mypage.pl',
            'name' => 'My Page',
            'caption' => $object->getTitle() ,
            'description' => 'Description....',
            'message' => $object->getText(),
          );

        $result = $facebook->api('/'.'$myAppId'.'/feed/', 'POST', $args);
        }

        //If the post is not published, print error details
        catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                     ....
        ));
        }
```

I am getting a response with id of app and a post id, I guess, like this:

```
{"status":"OK","content":{"id":"295131140562739_359030107506176"}}
```

But the post isn't shown on Facebook Fan Page Timeline. Any one implemented it with success?

Comment: I think you are trying to post the message on wrong page. You're making call to $myAppId/feed. Are you sure $myAppId is also id of the page where you want to post something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$result = $facebook->api('/'.'$myAppId'.'/feed/', 'POST', $args);
```

The above doesn't produce the desired effect. As Darvex mentioned, you probably don't want your app id there, but the page id. Also, putting a variable between single quotes in PHP will make it a string with the value $myAppId, not the value of the variable. That line should become:

```
$result = $facebook->api('/'. $myPageId .'/feed/', 'POST', $args);
```

Just make sure you assign the correct id to $myPageId before the call :)

Comment: Yep, there were two problems, one, that I've put there App id instead of Page ID. Second one, I wasn't logged in via admin page. I didn't create login URL with permissions etc. I thought it works without it and it looked like it worked cause I've got as a result a message id, but it didn't.